# Ubuntu: Execute shell script with fail2ban when user fails to log in ssh

Tags: ubuntu

In my ubuntu server I use fail2ban to block repeated failed ssh logins, when fail2ban detects this I want to execute a shell script, is this possible to do?

My ssh jail:

```
[ssh]
findtime = 10m
maxretry = 3
```

My shell script is in this location:

```
/home/MyUser/scripts/send-mail
```

Also, how can I get the banned IP? I want to send that information too if possible

Answer (score 0):

There are already predefined actions like `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/sendmail.conf` for sending email. You could simply enable one of them in your `[ssd]` jail with, e.g.,

```
sendmail[dest="[email]receiver@example.com[/email]", sender="[email]sender@example.com[/email]", sendername="Fail2Ban",
```

Comment: the thing is I send mails with mailgun (I didnt configure postfix or similar) so I use curl to send mail with mailgun efficently, that's why I need to call sh script